# Comparing "got used to", "have gotten used to", "get used to", "will get used to" and "have used to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I was going to somewhere by taxi in Delhi. Most of the drivers were
>   blowing their horns, *non-stop*! I asked my driver, "would you please stop
>   it? I am not in a rush." He said, "No *ma'am*! Because I am in a rush and the
>   others too." I said, "it seems you have not gotten used to traffic!" He
>   said, "No *ma'am*! We got used to it but now we want a change." I said, "but
>   this *non-stop* loud noise is making me crazy!" He laughed and said, "Yes
>   *ma'am* but please tolerate it for some hours. You will get used to it
>   like us!"

Would you please help me to get their differences? Above story helps you to find some examples of right and wrong usages.

Comment: The title is okay but it seems like another proof-reading.

Comment: You can ignore the story then answer me by your own examples to solve the problem by proofreading. It was an example to get what I mean. I made it just right now!

Comment: @Mistu4u  I think the title makes clear that OP is not asking us to correct the passage but to explain the 'tenses' and constructions employed.

Comment: You forgot some ""s and you misspelled some words (in *italics*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrasal verb *[to get used to](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=get+used+to&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=)* means to “get or become familiar or accustomed with through experience”, ie, to become habituated to something.

The several forms in the sample text –  *gotten used to*,  *got used to*,  *will get used to*  – merely show different forms of verb *to get*:  past participle *[gotten](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gotten)*, simple past *[got](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/got#Verb)*, and future *will get*, where *[will](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/will#Verb_2)* is an auxiliary expressing future tense.

Comment: @StoneyB, yes, that would be better; however, I've quoted the [wordnetweb](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=get+used+to&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) link as it is, rather than as it ought to be.

Comment: The same spelling "to get used to" is employed for both this phrasal verb and for an infinitive construct meaning "to employ [for some purpose]".  For example, "The motorist finally got used to traffic cameras" versus "The photography equipment smuggling ring, after a lull in business, finally got used to traffic cameras".

Answer (score 3):

> We used to live in India earlier where the weather is mostly sunny throughout the year. So when we first reached here in London 10 years back, we felt different with the cloudy weather here, but eventually we *got used to* this weather.

"Get used to"- to become habituated with or accustomed to a certain system in present.

"Have gotten used to-" means the action of being habituated with has still result in present i.e. it happened in the near past.

"Got used to"- means to become used to in past. So it means the action of habituated with happened a long time ago to make it past.

"Will get used to"- means to become used to in future.

**UPDATE**- "Near past" or "a long ago" are sometimes too vague to account for. So like StonyB commented, consider whether or not habituation is being treated as relevant at the time of utterance.

Comment: You've mostly got it; but I think that "a long time ago" and "near past" are irrelevant, and may mislead a Learner. "The cold bothered me when I arrived yesterday, but I got used to it quickly." "I arrived ten years ago, and I have gotten used to the cold." The only consideration is whether or not habituation is being treated as relevant at the time of utterance.

Comment: @StoneyB, Good point. Actually I agree with you, but when I was writing the answer,these perfectly describing words did not hit my mind! :)

Comment: @Mistu4u, "almost sunny" means not-quite sunny. I think you mean "mostly sunny," which means more often sunny than not.  Also, it should be "the year", not "a year". There are several other mistakes in your example text; would you like me to correct them?

Comment: There's an awful lot of what I suppose is "Indian English" in this answer. By my definition of "native speaker", we would never say something happened *"in near past"* or *"a long ago"*.

Comment: Is "have used to" conveying the same as "have gotten used to" or you do not have anything like this and it is grammatically wrong?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Agreed with you. It maybe the effect of Indian English. But _near past_ is a common usage in the grammar books here.

Comment: @ShawnMooney, Community editing is the best feature SE provides. Whenever you feel like editing, feel free to edit. :)

Comment: @user37324, I have never heard of `Have used to`. In the paragraph you provided, I can not see it. So I have no idea what it means. Can you provide context to test its usage?

Comment: @ShawnMooney, I am confused with _the year_. _A year_ specifies take any random year and I want to mean the same. _the_ specifies a particular year, which I do not want to mean. So how come _the_ is more applicable?

Comment: @Mistu4u: I'm no expert on Indian English, but I think it has a tendency to use/omit articles in non-standard ways. It's valid in Br. Eng. to say something *happened in **the** near past*, or *happened long ago*, but you can't omit the article in the first, or introduce one into the second.

Comment: @Mistu4u, when you use a preposition like "through" or "throughout", if it is followed by a countable noun, the following article must be "the", not "a/an".  I am an experienced grammar teacher but I am new to stackexchange, so please elaborate on your earlier comments about "community editing" if you don't mind.  Teach me!

Comment: Surely in my text you cannot find it. I have heard it from a non native.

Comment: @ShawnMooney, See [FAQ](http://ell.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)

Comment: @user37324, Then don't worry. It is likely to be a wrong usage. :)

Comment: Oh, What about had gotten used to it? Is this a habituating in the past that is finished with no result in the present, the time which speaker is talking in?